# Try-finally vs :with pool as"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Are these two blocks functionally the same, especially with properly closing connections?

Try-finally block:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fun_parallel(processes=4):
    try:
        pool = Pool(processes=processes)
        results = [pool.apply_async(SOMEFUNCTION, iter_item) for iter_item in SOMELIST]
        results_list = [r.get() for r in results]
        return results_list
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

vs

With pool block:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fun_parallel(processes=4):
    with Pool(processes=processes) as p:
        results = [p.apply_async(SOMEFUNCTION, iter_item) for iter_item in SOMELIST]
        results_list = [r.get() for r in results]
        return results_list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not equivalent, but it only matters if there was an exception.

Using a pool object as a context manager will cause the [`Pool.terminate()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pool.terminate) to be called on exit. From the [Process Pools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):

> Pool objects now support the context management protocol [...] `__enter__()` returns the pool object, and `__exit__()` calls `terminate()`.

`Pool.terminate()` ends all child processes immediately, without waiting for work to complete.

What you use is up to your application. The context manager would only exit *before* work is completed if there was an exception. Your version *waits for other work to complete first*, before propagating the exception.

Because you are collecting the completed work in a list comprehension, if there are no exceptions raised you'll not see a difference in behaviour. Terminating may be a little faster than closing and joining, however. Both methods will close the connections properly.